# Data placement in memory

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c, memory, buffer-overflow

I am playing with buffer overflow attacks in C. I have the following code:

```
int foo(void*, void*);        // Calculates the distance (in bytes) between two addresses in memory

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int a = 15;
   int b = 16;
   int c = 90;

   char buffer[4];
   
   /* Memory layout */
   printf("[LAYOUT]\n");
   printf("foo(&a, &b) is %d\n", foo(&a, &b));
   printf("foo(&a, &c) is %d\n", foo(&a, &c));
   printf("foo(&c, &string) is %d\n", foo(&c, &string));
   printf("foo(&a, &string) is %d\n\n", foo(&a, &string));

   /* Memory content before copying into the buffer */
   printf("[BEFORE]\n");
   printf("a is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &a, a, a);
   printf("b is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &b, b, b);
   printf("c is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &c, c, c);
   printf("string is at %p and is %s\n\n", &string, string);

   strcpy(buffer, "aaaaaaaaa");

   /* Memory content after copying into the buffer */
   printf("[AFTER]\n");
   printf("a is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &a, a, a);
   printf("b is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &b, b, b);
   printf("c is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &c, c, c);
   printf("string is at %p and is %s\n", &string, string);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int foo(void* addr_1, void* addr_2) {
   return (addr_1 - addr_2);
}
```

After the compilation with `gcc main.c -o main -O0 -g -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` flags **with optimization turned off**, the output is following (*on my machine*):

```
[LAYOUT]
foo(&a, &b) is 4
foo(&a, &c) is 8
foo(&c, &string) is 4
foo(&a, &string) is 12

[BEFORE]
a is at 0x7ffee13d5b68 and is 16 (0x00000010)
b is at 0x7ffee13d5b64 and is 15 (0x0000000f)
c is at 0x7ffee13d5b60 and is 90 (0x0000005a)
string is at 0x7ffee13d5b5c and is 

[AFTER]
a is at 0x7ffee13d5b68 and is 16 (0x00000010)
b is at 0x7ffee13d5b64 and is 97 (0x00000061)
c is at 0x7ffee13d5b60 and is 1633771873 (0x61616161)
string is at 0x7ffee13d5b5c and is aaaaaaaaa
```

Obviously, the buffer is located at the leftmost position, before integer variables. I can think of it as:

| 0x5c | 0x5d | 0x5e | 0x5f | 0x60 | 0x61 | 0x62 | 0x63 | 0x64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 | 0x61 |

It completely overwrites `c`'s data (all four bytes) and the one byte of `b`'s data (*little-endian machine*).

After compiling the same program with the optimization turned on, `-O1` for example, it produces the output:

```
[LAYOUT]
foo(&a, &b) is -4
foo(&a, &c) is -8
foo(&c, &string) is 12
foo(&a, &string) is 4

[BEFORE]
a is at 0x7ffee056db3c and is 16 (0x00000010)
b is at 0x7ffee056db40 and is 15 (0x0000000f)
c is at 0x7ffee056db44 and is 90 (0x0000005a)
string is at 0x7ffee056db38 and is 

[AFTER]
a is at 0x7ffee056db3c and is 1633771873 (0x61616161)
b is at 0x7ffee056db40 and is 97 (0x00000061)
c is at 0x7ffee056db44 and is 90 (0x0000005a)
string is at 0x7ffee056db38 and is aaaaaaaaa
```

It seems to me that integer variables are placed in memory in reversed order.

The questions are:

1. **How does a variable declaration and/or initialization in C affect its placement in memory?**
2. **Does the optimization affect on variable placement in memory? If so, then how?**

The working environment is `macOS Mojave 10.14.6`, `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)`

Comment: You might find that this is compiler dependent.. this is not part of the C standard.